# JQuery - stop all audio at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I created a javascript audio player and i stored all media in this format:

```
var audios = {
    fade: new Audio('music/fade.mp3'),
    spectre: new Audio('music/spectre.mp3'),
    force: new Audio('music/force.mp3')
}
```

and I am trying to stop them all with just one function, I am using `audios['fade'].play()`, `audios['spectre'].play()` and `audios['force'].play()` to play them.

Comment: "with just one function"? So, what are you waiting for? Create a function, iterate through the object and call the `pause` method of each audio.

Comment: @Vohuman i mean something like loop, like Jason explained in his answer.

Comment: So the question is: how can I iterate through an object?

Comment: @Vohuman yes, you can edit my question if you want. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably pass your audios object to a function with a for in loop to cycle through each property of your passed in object and turn it off.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: Great, please mark this as your excepted answer then :)

Answer (score -1):

o

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    var obj = document.createElement("audio");
        obj.src = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/week7-brrring.m4a";
        obj.volume = 0.1;
        obj.autoPlay = false;
        obj.controls = true;
        $('span.playAudio').not('hidden').click(function(){
          obj.play();
          setTimeout(function(){
            obj.pause();
            obj.currentTime = 0;
        }, 1000);
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="playAudio">Play</span>
```

bj.pause();
obj.currentTime = 0;